# Is there a way to control Apps like Puppeteer/Selenium controls browser?

Tags: node.js, automation

I have to control Whatsapp Desktop App in a similar way that Puppeter/Selenium controls browser, is there any way?

I am not findind any library that can do this.

I am using Node.js, and searching preferably a node library. But in Python will do too.

Comment: What OS?  For Windows see: AutoHotKey.  Windows apps that do this send mouse and keyboard input to windows using the win32 APU to try to automate them.